# Loop through cell range (Every 3 cells) and add ranking to it

Tags: python, pandas, loops, range, cell

The problem is I am trying to make a ranking for every 3 cells in that column
using pandas. 
For example:

[This is the outcome I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSTNS.png)
I have no idea how to make it.

I tried something like this:

```
for i in range(df.iloc[1:],df.iloc[,:],3):
counter = 0
i['item'] += counter + 1
```

The code is completely wrong, but I need help with the range and put df.iloc in the brackets in pandas.

Comment: Refer [How to create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this match the requirements ?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Item'] = ['shoes','shoes','shoes','shirts','shirts','shirts']

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i, item in enumerate(df['Item'].unique(), 1):
  df2.loc[i-1,'rank'] = i
  df2.loc[i-1, 'Item'] = item

df2['rank'] = df2['rank'].astype('int')
print(df)
print("\n")
print(df2)

df = df.merge(df2, on='Item', how='inner')
print("\n")
print(df)
```

Comment: But I do not want it to be in alphabetical order. I want it by initial row.